# SQLAlchemy: Understanding Select statements within transactions

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, transactions

I'm trying to understand the behavior of SQLAlchemy `Sessions` and their relations to PostgreSQL transactions, as they don't seem to behave quite the same. I've created a simple program to insert, update, and subsequently update a row:

```py
engine = sa.create_engine(f"postgresql+psycopg2://{pg_user}:@{pg_host}:{pg_port}/{pg_db}", echo=True)
Base = declarative_base()

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine, expire_on_commit=True)
session = Session()

# Add a user
u1 = User(id=1, name="u1")
session.add(u1)
session.commit()

# Modify user's name
session.query(User).filter_by(id=1).update({"name": "u2"})
session.commit()

# Get user's name
user = session.query(User).filter_by(id=1).one()
print(user.name) # prints "u2" as expected
```

However, if I now remove the `session.commit()` statement between the modification and select, I get an unexpected result:

```py
# ...

# Modify user's name
session.query(User).filter_by(id=1).update({"name": "u2"})

# Get user's name
user = session.query(User).filter_by(id=1).one()
print(user.name) # prints "u1" -- NOT expected!
```

Presumably this is because the session is querying the database, in which the user's name has not been updated (because the transaction has not yet been committed). However, I would have thought that because I'm using the same `session` object to query the user, it should recognize the changes that have occurred on the User object within the transaction.

What am I not understanding here?

Comment: I can't reproduce this behaviour (on 2.0.19), but you might want to review [this section](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/queryguide/dml.html#orm-update-and-delete-with-custom-where-criteria) of the docs.

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL uses "[Read Committed](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/transaction-iso.html)" isolation level. This means that the each query being executed sees data committed earlier.

So, when you are making changes without "session.commit()", the changes are not made in the database, so the queries does not see those changes. Once you have committed the changes, the changes are made in database and upcoming queries within same session will see updated data.

To avoid "session.commit()" after every query, you can set "autocommit" to true.

Comment: My initial question seems to be more related to the behavioral differences between a SQLAlchemy Session object vs. a PostgreSQL transaction, rather than the isolation level of PostgreSQL itself. Understood that PostgreSQL uses Read Committed isolation level, but from the docs you linked: `However, SELECT does see the effects of previous updates executed within its own transaction, even though they are not yet committed.` This does not seem to be happening with the SQLAlchemy session object.